# Links in Content Block

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a few links in the home page. for e.g. link1 , link2, link3
When I click link1 want to load the page link1.phtml , link2 to load link2.phtml and link3 to load link3.phtml

Know it is possible to create a page in admin cms and then loading the page. But is it possible to do it in the local.xml file without touching the admin .  The reason is I have about 15 links on the home page that needs to be showing some information.

Please can anyone help with the codes

New Link

How to map this to a link or please correct me if my approach is wrong

Comment: you need separate page for each .phtml file

Comment: yes, I do have seperate page for each .phtml page, but please how to map them  to <ahref='whattogivehere'>link 1</a>

Comment: you have to create custom module for this

Comment: is it going to be very tough or easy, please can  you send any links or a short example to start with

Comment: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller

Comment: Ok, so how do i call this module in a href or link, pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [**Link**](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller) to create custom module with controller

Then create new actions for each links in your controller file

> app/code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controllers/IntegerController.php

```
public function link1Action()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Now you have change the content of each page, So you need to change in layout file

> app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/arithmetic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     ...
    <arithmetic_integer_link1>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="arithmetic_integer_multiply" template="yourfolder/link1.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </arithmetic_integer_link1>
    ...
</layout>
```

Like this you can add more action for each links.

To link for these pages

```
$this->getUrl('arithmetic/integer/link1');
```

Here 
arithmetic ->your module name
integer -> your controller
link1 -> your action.

Comment: <routers>
            <Bibliografi>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bibliografi_Homecatg</module>
                    <frontName>homecatg</frontName>
                </args>
            </Bibliografi>
        </routers>
  <layout>
            <updates>
     <Bibliografi>
                    <file>homecatg.xml</file>
                </Bibliografi>
            </updates>
        </layout> but the homecatg.xml is nto called at all, any help please,